# PhoneGap - Build error

Tags: cordova

I'm very new to phonegap and tried to create a simple test app by entering the commands like described on the phonegap [install](http://phonegap.com/install/) webpage

Unfortunately, I get the following error in the command-line:

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:284: null returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,E:\Projects\Mobile\P
honeGap\test-app\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.
dir=ant-gen
   [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I use Windows 7 64-bit. My environment variables look like the following:

```
ANDROID_HOME = E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK
ANT_HOME = E:\Projects\Mobile\Eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Nevertheless, if I type in "ant" in the command shell, I get the following message:

> E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app>ant
>
> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
>
> Build failed

Could that probably be the reason?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the complete output in the commandline:

```
E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[ReferenceError: a is not defined]
Buildfile: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\
ant-build\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\
ant-build\rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\
CordovaLib\ant-build\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\
CordovaLib\ant-build\rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-
app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\a
ndroid\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\plat
forms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\plat
forms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\plat
forms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\plat
forms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\and
roid\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\pla
tforms\android\ant-build\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\ant-bu
ild\classes
      [dex] input: E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\Cordov
aLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing E:\Projects\Mobile\PhoneGap\test-app\platforms\android\Co
rdovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar -> classes-e1aa4bb1e6a0a2f38f9e3036d5cbe6f6.jar
       [dx] 'E:\ProgramFiles' is not recognized as an internal or external comma
nd,
       [dx] operable program or batch file.

BUILD FAILED
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK\tools\ant\build.xml:284: null returned: 1

Total time: 2 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,E:\Projects\Mobile\P
honeGap\test-app\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.
dir=ant-gen
   [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Comment: `ant` is expected to fail if run from the root level of your project. PhoneGap runs it from a sub-dir, where the build.xml folder is located in your android platform

Comment: try deleting the android folder and rebuild with `phonegap local build android`.

Comment: the line `[ReferenceError: a is not defined]` is suspicious. No idea where its coming from (check your config.xml?) but good indication of something wrong.

Comment: Thanks  Xenocideae for your tips. I moved the Android SDK to the E: drive and it works now. Interestingly, the ReferenceError did not vanish. I cannot say what might be the reason why this error appears.

Comment: I got the same error, but for me the cause was an invalid icon path and an invalid theme in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I just added <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />, and I got this error. Removed it and the error is no longer there. HTH

Comment: The same Error I also getting. Please provide some detailed answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the error log you'll see the message

```
E:\ProgramFiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

You configured `ANDROID_HOME = E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK` which seems weird for me because normally the folder is named `C:\Program Files (x86)` (with a space).

Is your AndroidSDK really installed in the folder named E:\ProgramFiles(x86)?
I don't really think it's the issue, since the SDK seems to be found, but I had to ask anyway...

More likelly, I think that somewhere in the cordova build scripts there may be a line that doesn't like the  round brackets () in the path.

To ckeck this without messing with your conf, you can try this in a cmd (changes will be lost after closing the cmd):

```
subst z: E:\ProgramFiles(x86)\AndroidSDK
set ANDROID_HOME=z:\
phonegap build android
```

(replace Z with an other lerrer if you're already using the Z drive)

Comment: QuickFix, fortunately I could quickly fix this issue by moving the Android SDK to E:\. Thanks very much for your hint!

Answer (score 7):

Renaming the android folder and again running the 'phonegap local build android' worked for me when I had the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by delete of content these folders:

```
/platforms/android/ant-build
/platforms/android/ant-gen
/platforms/android/bin
/platforms/android/gen
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get the error

> Command failed with exit code 2

The cause can be because of your android SDK not fully or correctly installed. To solve this you can try to edit the file `\platforms\android\project.properties` and change

```
target=android-22
```

To something like

```
target=android-21
```

Or another target in which you have successfully built app in the past. This will download a new gradle and that's all you need to build your project.

Answer (score 2):

That happens when you change the `version` tag from "0.0.1" to "0.1" on the `config.xml` file.

But according to the PhoneGap doc, it must be major/minor/patch :

> The  element's id attribute provides the app's reverse-domain
>   identifier, and the version its full version number expressed in
>   major/minor/patch notation.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html

Answer (score 2):

Remove your platform and add it again .It solved my problem

Remove android platform:

ionic platform rm android

Add it again:

ionic platform add android

make sure that you take backup of res folder. if you have any icons or splash screens..

Comment: It helped :) Thanks, although in my end I needed to do:

cordova platform remove android
Then
cordova platform add android

Anyway it solved the issue. :)
Thanks,
Chen

Comment: glad that i could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

My story was that I somehow managed to have *two* `node_modules` folders, one in the root of my Phonegap project and another one inside the `www` of the AngularJS app I was trying to "port" using Phonegap. I received a stacktrace such as

```
..
unable to process assets while packaging
<..>\node_modules\semver\semver.browser.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
..
<..>\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: 1
```

Also received a `\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8` but I don't know if the two errors are related.

Deleting the `node_modules` folder from the `www` folder did the trick. Running Win7 x64.

Comment: had the same issue here, following this http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap step by step led me to this error. I guess some project setup changed here which brings this problem.