# Error 'ionic run Android' on device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

So, I'm simply trying to run my app on a plugged in HTC Desire. The steps I've taken are: enabling debugging in the manifest xml, enabled usb debugging on the device itself, and created the AVD with a custom definition in the android AVD manager.

The errors I'm getting after running `ionic run android --info`

"Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"
"Could not reserve enough space for object heap", as well as the warning 
"No target specified, deploying device [random device number that i have no clue where it's coming from]"

Here's an image of my command window:
[image]

Any ideas why i might have this warning and error messages? Are they related issues? or are they two seperate issues?

Comment: Are you using a 32bit JDK on Windows 64bit? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950241/phonegap-run-android-gives-error

Comment: I thought that I had already check that as an optional solution, but I double-checked and realized that my path variable was referring to the old version of jdk/jre (32 bit). After fixing that, and re-building the ionic app so that the changes were fully implemented in the new build, it runs on the device just fine! Thanks for your help @QueryLars

Comment: To guys looking for solving this issue, this helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34636929/3748701

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me

> Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment
>   Variables->System Variables->New:

**Variable name**: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`

**Variable value**: `-Xmx512M`

Comment: Works in windows too, adding the same variable in environment, thx for help

Answer (score 3):

Add _JAVA_OPTIONS to your Environment Variables with the value -Xms512M

[image: Environment]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\ directory and try again.