# ionic platform add android error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\gizem\Desktop\proje\IonicFileTransferDemo
\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)

```
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Help me !!! Please

Comment: i having the same error. You got any solution for this?

Comment: i found a similiar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342629/error-ionic-run-android-on-device. But that didnt solve my problem