# Deploying an App to an Android device via Cordova

Tags: cordova

I am currently studying with the Open University and the module I'm on requires me to deploy and provided app to an Android device.  We're using Cordova through Command Line to do this, and I've hit an error.  I've asked around at Uni and no one seems to be able to help.  I hope you guys can.

I have Cordova set up and I've built my project.  However, when I envoke Cordova to build the Android side of things with 'cordova build android', I get the error in the picture shown:

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRr2.png)

I don't have a lot of experience in this area, so I'm really looking for some advice on what may have caused the issue please.

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: It might be useful to include the error text into the question so that it's searchable for others.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950241/phonegap-run-android-gives-error